# Upload image call API upload Mobile

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am using an API to upload an image and return a link.

I don't know how to use this API to upload image from Mobile. Please help me.

Code:

```
  const { file } = payload;
  console.log('file', file);
  
  const params = {
    Key: `${file.hapi.filename}`,
    Body: file,
    ContentType: file.hapi.headers['content-type']
  };
  const image = await s3.uploadFile(params);
  return { image: image.Location };
```

Comment: first, you have to find how do API accept the data because there is several ways to send media throw API

Comment: I test on postman and return link in amazon. and the file API accept is Readable{...}. But from Mobile I just accept uri file